# What are the major differences between Fluxbox and Blackbox?

Tags: window-manager, fluxbox

I'm considering switching to either Fluxbox or Blackbox as my window manager, but I'm not really sure which one to go with.

Are there any major differences between the two ?

Comment: dude. openbox, waaaay nicer.

Comment: @nathwill - Why not post an answer about openbox? I'd be very curious to learn why it is better than fluxbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important difference is probably that Fluxbox is still actively developed, while Blackbox's last cvs commit seems to have been in 2005.

Another important difference is that Fluxbox has various features that Blackbox does not - most notably:

- You can use tabs to group multiple windows together
- Fluxbox has a system tray/notification area
- Fluxbox supports key bindings out of the box while blackbox requires a separate tool (taken from The Alpha Nerd's answer)

Comment: you mind adding a link to that commit

Answer (score 2):

Also, Blackbox needs a bbkeys program for keyboard shortcuts, while flux has them integrated. This makes it lighter.